# Нормирование размера картинок

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.7, pil

Есть такая функция. Я загружаю картинки разного размера. Можно ли как-то сделать вывод картинок в одинаковом размере?

```
def load_photo(event):
    filename=askopenfilename()
    #send photo
    json_string =client.faces_detect(file=(filename))
    #print(json_string)

    canvas = Canvas(width = 200, height = 200, bg = 'white')
    canvas.delete()
    canvas.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = filename)
    canvas.create_image(10, 10, image = image, anchor = NW)
    #detection eyes
    canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,100,100,width=3,outline='green')
    textbox.insert('1.0',json_string)
    mainloop()
```